# What triggers dropbox on fedora to upload files?

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, dropbox

I am writing a computer simulation on a Fedora system, but wants to postprocess the data using MATLAB on a windows installation. My method for transferring files is Dropbox since the two computers are on separate corporate networks (and other hassle). The final output generating step at the linux system is parsing the output data with a bash script to cast it into a m-file format. This kind of file creation (by bahs script sh-file) doesnt seem to trigger Dropbox to sync. My manually renameing the file and revert causes immediate upload to Dropbox. (`mv myfile.m myfile2.m; mv myfile2.m myfile.m` from shell ). The question I have for you is a bit more general:

What actions triggers Dropbox on Fedora to push file updates to the cloud?

Comment: Where are your files located? Is it on a network mount or local disk? This post may be relevant assuming your files are located on a network mount: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231243/inotify-with-nfs

Comment: They're local and it's the standard install of Dropbox. The folder that is monitored is in the location ~/Dropbox I can't recall offhand my file system used, but it is the default partitioning options for Fedora 20.